# Speed up query which uses common table expression

Tags: postgresql

Is there any better way to improve such query which uses `common languge extension` in the means on speedness?

This is my query:

```
'with s as (select a.idx, false hot
    from myschemaA.TableA a
    join myschemaA.TableB b on a.tkid=b.tkid and a.sdx=b.sdx
    where a.hot=true)
update myschemaA.TableA d set hot=s.hot, insightsdcd=clock_timestamp(), insightslud=clock_timestamp()
from s where d.idx=s.idx',
```

Comment: Does that not depend a little on the schema and number of records.?

Comment: Please show relevant tables and indexes.

Comment: A 'common language extension' and a 'common table expression' are different things.

Comment: @jjanes just typo mistake apologize

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a self-joined CTE here, you can just do a normal joined update.

```
update myschemaA.TableA a
set hot = false,
    insightsdcd = clock_timestamp(),
    insightslud = clock_timestamp()
from myschemaA.TableB b
where a.tkid = b.tkid
  and a.sdx = b.sdx
  and a.hot = true;
```

For this to perform efficiently, I would say you need the following indexes

```
TableA (hot, sdx, tkid)    -- sdx and tkid in either order
TableB (sdx, tkid)         -- same order as TableA
```

Alternatively you can use a filtered index

```
TableA (sdx, tkid)    -- sdx and tkid in either order
    WHERE (hot = true)
```

Comment: If column ‘hot’ only has values True, False and NULL, then an index with hot’ in the first segment will only be beneficial if there are relatively few hot=True records.  And of course updating that column is expensive.

Comment: True, which is why I suggested the filtered index as an alternative. Without knowing cardinalities we can't say more.